# Linux Bible 10th Edition: are permissions calculated right with umask?

Tags: umask

I read *"Linux Bible 10th Edition"*, **chapter 4: Becoming a Linux Power User**, at 109 page. Second paragraph:

```
$ umask
0002
```

> If you ignore the leading zero for the moment, the umask value masks what is considered
> to be fully opened permissions for a file 666 or a directory 777. The umask value of 002
> results in permission for a directory of 755 (`rwxrwxr-x`). That same umask results in a file permission of 644 (`rw-rw-r--`). (Execute permissions are off by default for regular files.)

I wonder why umask value of 002 is calculated for file like 644? As I understood 666 - 002 = 664. Btw, permissions in parentheses looks like 664.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's got errors.

Here's what it should say,

> If you ignore the leading zero for the moment, the umask value masks what is considered to be fully opened permissions for a file 666 or a directory 777. The umask value of 002 results in permission for a directory of 775 (rwxrwxr-x). That same umask results in a file permission of 664 (rw-rw-r--). (Execute permissions are off by default for regular files.)

The symbolic permissions are correct for the specified `umask`. The octal values are not. (This is one reason why it's almost always better to use symbolic permissions with `chmod` - it's far easier to see what is intended and can be less prone to typo mistakes.)